# Google Translate using Flags

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

I have a Google Translate drop down menu at the moment which is used for 6 different languages only. This is as follows at the moment:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', 
        includedLanguages: 'ar,de,en,es,fr,it', layout: 
        google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL}, 
        'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js
    cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I am trying to change this so that instead of showing as drop down menus it shows as flags inline and then when each flag is clicked on it updates with the relevant language.

An example of this can be seen [here](http://www.coachhire4u.com/)

They also use Google Translate.

I have tried to look at the code they have added for this including the javascript [here](http://www.coachhire4u.com/wp-content/plugins/google-language-translator/js/flags.js?ver=4.4.16) but I am still struggling to get this to work.

If anyone can help or offer any advice on this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

To update. The script provided by Google generates the following coding:

```
<div id="google_translate_element">
    <div class="skiptranslate goog-te-gadget" dir="ltr" style="">
        <div id=":0.targetLanguage" style="display: inline;">
            <select class="goog-te-combo" aria-label="Language Translate Widget">
                <option value="">Select Language</option>
                <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
                <option value="fr">French</option>
                <option value="de">German</option>
                <option value="it">Italian</option>
                <option value="es">Spanish</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I need I assume to use jQuery to then change this code to display as li lists and not select.

Can anyone help with this.

Thanks

Comment: That website is effectively hiding the standard dropdown using `display:none`. And on top of that, they are programmatically trigerring the `onChange` event of the `goo-te-combo` dropdown, whenever a flag is clicked. The flags themselves are just standard custom made HTML from what I can tell.

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: @mogelbrod I noticed you did something similar to this back in 2012. Is this something you can help with?